# Erro 404 com CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou tendo o seguinte erro com o Codeigniter: 
URL:http://192.168.33.10/crudex/index.php/user_controller

"404 Page Not Found, The page requested was not found."

Código do Controller:

```
<?php  
if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed');

class User_controller extends CI_Controller {

    // Controlador Padrão
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('control_panel');
    }

    // Controlador de adição
    function add() {
        $this->load->view('add_panel');
    }

    // Controlador de edição
    function edit() {
        $result = $this->uri->segment(3);
        if ($result == NULL) {
            redirect('user_controller');
        }

        $pointer = $this->user_model->edit($result);
        $data['user_name'] = $pointer->user_name;
        $data['user_email'] = $pointer->user_email;
        $data['id_user'] = $pointer;

        $this->load->view('edit_panel', $data);
    }

    function delete() {
        $pointer = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->user_model->delete($pointer);
        redirect('user_controller');
    }

    // Controlador de 'save'
    function save() {
        if($this->('mit')) {
            $this->user_model->add();
            redirect('user_controller');
        } else {
            redirect('user_controller');
        }
    }

    // Controlador de atualização
    function update() {
        if($this->input->post('mit')) {
            $id = $this->input->post('user_id');
            this->user_model->update($id);
            redirect('user_controller');
        } else {
                redirec('user_controller');
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Essa sua URL é do seu IP local, não vamos conseguir acessar de fora de sua rede, você subiu esse código em algum servidor?

Comment: Eu utilizo uma vagrant box chamada Scotch Box

Comment: Conseguiu ajustar?

Comment: Mas ai você tem que chamar o método index e não chamar a classe, na url

Answer (score 0):

Essa sua url ta errada, o que seria crudex?
Acho q sua url correta seria:

```
http://192.168.33.10/index.php/user_controller
```

Comment: Não funcionou...

Comment: Pode ser seu htacess ou conf.d tas usando apache ou nginx?
Como está sua estrutura de pastas?

Comment: É apache, estava funcionando normal até ontem...
Link da organização de pastas: https://www.flickr.com/photos/143995297@N06/shares/1b92G4